# Pushing variable to an existing function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, push

So, lets say I have a function like this

```
(function($){
   $.fn.test = function(opts){
      var   _object = $(this),
            _opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.test.defaults, opts),
            _callback = _opts.objects[1].callback

      /* some code here */

      _callback() /* calling for a callback */
   }

   $.fn.test.defaults = { 
      /* not that important for now */
   }
})
```

That's how I initialise that function

```
$('.element').test({ 
   option: 0,   /* not important */
   variable: 1, /* not important */
   objects: [ 
      { 
         "object"   : ".element2",
         "callback" : false
      }, 
      { 
         "object"   : ".element3", /* THIS IS OBJECT № 2 */
         "callback" : function(){ 
            /* >>> {THIS PART} <<< */
            console.log (this)
         }
      },
   ]
```

So on **{THIS PART}** it just returns the data of object №2, but I would like the callback function to run on my **_object** element from **$.fn.test** so it would output the data of **$('.element')**. I can't make it hardcoded, and can't put instead `console.log (this)` just `console.log ($('.element'))` - as I'm trying to make more dynamic function. So I need to replace **this** with my **_object** element at the moment when it's calling for a callback right here `_callback() /* calling for a callback */` . I definitely can't use replace as it's not a string, but I had an idea to convert function to a string, change what I need and then convert to function - but that sounds like inappropriate solution.

Do you have any ideas in your mind? What can you suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if you want to get the $.fn.test scope you can try something like this:

```
$.fn.test = function(opts){
  var _object = $(this),
      _opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.test.defaults, opts),
      _callback = _opts.objects[1].callback;

  _callback(this);
}
```

and

```
$('.element').test({ 
   option: 0,
   variable: 1,
   objects: [ 
      { 
         "object": ".element2",
         "callback": false
      }, 
      { 
         "object": ".element3",
         "callback" : function(parentScope){ 
            console.log(parentScope);
         }
      },
   ] 
});
```

Comment: I find it very useful, simple, and fixing my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note, If interpret question correctly , requirement to return `_object = $(this)` as `this` at `console.log (this)` `_callback` ?

Try

```
    (function($){
       $.fn.test = function(opts){
          var _object = $(this),
                _opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.test.defaults, opts),
                _callback = _opts.objects[1].callback;

          /* some code here */
          // call `_object` as `this` at `_callback`
          _callback.call(_object) /* calling for a callback */


       $.fn.test.defaults = { 
          /* not that important for now */
       }
    }
    }(jQuery));
```

See [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) , [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) , [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
    (function($){
       $.fn.test = function(opts){
          var _object = $(this),
                _opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.test.defaults, opts),
                _callback = _opts.objects[1].callback;
    
          /* some code here */
          // call `_object` as `this` at `_callback`
          _callback.call(_object) /* calling for a callback */
    
    
       $.fn.test.defaults = { 
          /* not that important for now */
       }
    }
    }(jQuery));

$('html').test({ 
   objects: [ 
      { 
         "object"   : ".element2",
         "callback" : false
      }, 
      { 
         "object"   : ".element3", /* THIS IS OBJECT № 2 */
         "callback" : function(){ 
            /* >>> {THIS PART} <<< */
            console.log(this);
            $(this).find("body").append(this[0].tagName)
         }
      },
   ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```